# Puppet agent couldn't request certificate: Header too long

Tags: ssl-certificate, puppet, ntp

Previously, I had the agent working properly, but after a recent power outage, I keep getting this issue.

I run puppet agent -t and get this error:

> Error: Could not request certificate: Neither PUB key nor PRIV key: header too long

I've googled the issue, and it sounded like a clock issue (also suspected due to power outage). The time was off by 4 hours, but BIOS time seemed correct when I checked it. ntpdate didn't seem to work, so I synchronized them manually. Additionally, I've looked at the public and private keys after someone mentioned stray characters in their post, but haven't found anything of the sort.

Both master and agent are running Ubuntu, 15.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with help from Puppet IRC

rm -rf $ssldir ON THE AGENT; puppet cert clean $certname on the master
then puppet agent -t on the agent and get new certs

Due to corruption from power loss.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error, but only removing the ssl directory wan't enough for me... but this fixed it:

```
apt-get purge puppet puppet-common puppetlabs-release hiera facter
rm -rf /var/lib/puppet /etc/puppet
apt-get purge augeas-lenses libaugeas-ruby libaugeas0 ruby-augeas ruby-json ruby-shadow virt-what
```

Then reinstall it. This puppet agent is version 3.8.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Also just the first purge line and `rm -rf ...` didn't fix it alone. I guess some file got corrupted (although the disks were never replaced and look fine, and it has ECC RAM) or something was generated and was wrong due to some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issues was was from lack of disk space on master and cert on master that needed to be deleted from `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/ca/requests`